# How to plot first and second row from matrix to a graph

Tags: matrix, plotting

i have this function:

```
CreateMatrix[maxRows_, maxColumns_] := {
  Rows = RandomInteger[{2, maxRows}];
  Columns = RandomInteger[{2, maxColumns}];

  Mat = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {Rows, Columns}];

  FirstRow = Mat[[1]];
  SecondRow = Mat[[2]];

  Print[Mat // MatrixForm];
}
```

Do you have any ideas, how to plot a point graph(from function) via ListPlot?

FirstRow are X values, SecondRow are Y values, like this:

FirstRow = {x1, x2, x3, ...};
SencondRow = {y1, y2, y3, ...};

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Transpose function, it would be like:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{row,col}]]
```